# Why isn't kpathsea picking up my local version of a file?

Tags: file-lookup

I've just made a minor alteration to a file from a TeX package.  I copied it into my local texmf tree and made the change there.  When I tried `kpsewhich <filename>` to test that it was finding my local version, it returned the original one and not the new one.  In actual fact, the original file was from my local texmf tree already so I renamed the old one something simple.  Now `kpsewhich <filename>` returned the *system* version of the file.  To check that the file was there, I tried `kpsewhich -all <filename>` and got the correct two versions of the file: my modified one and the system one (in that order).  If I try this with another file that I know exists in both places, then `kpsewhich <filename>` returns my local file.

Here's the various invocations and their results:

```
~% kpsewhich pgfsys-pdftex.def
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
~% kpsewhich -all pgfsys-pdftex.def 
/Users/stacey/Library/texmf/tex/latex/bzr/pgfsys-pdftex.def
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
~% kpsewhich tqft.sty              
/Users/stacey/Library/texmf/tex/latex/bzr/tqft.sty
~% kpsewhich -all tqft.sty
/Users/stacey/Library/texmf/tex/latex/bzr/tqft.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tqft/tqft.sty
```

Is it something special about the `.def` extension?  Is there some command that I forgot to run?  Are there some other options to `kpsewhich` that will help me debug this?

Comment: kpsewhich doesn't search first the complete local tree and then the global tree but first one path in the local tree, then this path in the global tree, then the second path in the local tree and so on. So put the file in `/Users/stacey/Library/texmf/tex/generic/`

Comment: I didn't know that!  Thanks - it works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good point! You could make this to an answer or Andrew. We could close as too localized, however I guess the explanation of this issue could help other users who just google instead of reading the kpathsea manual.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`kpsewhich` (and `kpathsea` generally) doesn't search first the complete local tree and then the global tree but use a sort of zigzag road: first one path in the local tree is searched, then this path in the global tree, then the second path in the local tree and so on.

The exact road depends on the engine, e.g. the road is different for `latex` and `xelatex`, and the settings in `texmf.cnf`. The details can be found in the `kpathsea` manual.

This zigzag is useful. E.g. you can have engine dependant configuration files: you can have a `hyphen.cfg` in your local tree in `tex/xelatex` and another in the global tree in `tex/latex`, and `xelatex` will use the local one and `latex` the other.

So put your file in `/Users/stacey/Library/texmf/tex/generic/` so that it lays in the same subpath than the global one.