# MiKTeX order of precedence for duplicate files

Tags: miktex, compiling, input

I am using MiKTeX under a single-user installation. My MiKTeX Options dialogue shows me, if I click on the "Show MiKTeX-maintained root directories" checkbox, directories in the following order (from top to bottom):

- `C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9`
- `C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9`
- `C:\Users\<my_username>\user_software\localtexmf`
- `C:\Users\<my_username>\user_software\miktex`
- `C:\Program Data\MiKTeX\2.9`
- `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\2.9`

I do not have the option to move anything using the "Up" or "Down" button.

Something in the way the precedence order for duplicate filenames is processed is not working. Here is what's specifically causing me trouble:

---

I put the latest version of the `glyphtounicode.tex` file (from [LCDF Type Software](http://www.lcdf.org/type/)) into the folder `C:\Users\<my_username>\user_software\localtexmf\tex\plain\lcdf-typetools`. However because an older version of this same file was put (by MiKTeX) into the folder `C:\Users\<my_username>\user_software\miktex\tex\generic\pdftex`, the version that `pdflatex` reads is always that older one, not the one in my `localtexmf` folder.

For now, I have resorted to renaming the newer version to `glyphtounicodeupdated.tex` and using `\input{glyphtounicodeupdated}` instead of `\input{glyphtounicode}`, but there should be a way of using `\input{glyphtounicode}` with `pdflatex` using that correct, newer version. How can I achieve this?

(I always refresh the filename database. So that shouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: Put your file in a similar folder substructure than the other one. That means use `\localtexmf\tex\generic\pdftex` and not `\localtexmf\text\plain\...`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79968/why-isnt-kpathsea-picking-up-my-local-version-of-a-file/79983#79983

Comment: Why not go for the simple solution and use the MiKTeX package manager to remove the older version? This avoids any further issues of precedence.

Comment: @Alexander I don't know how: I don't know which package it comes with.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As far as I can tell, `ushyphex.tex` has no duplicate, but conceptually it belongs into a folder `localtexmf\tex\plain\ushyphex`, correct?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to make your first comment an answer? Btw I think you mean `\localtexmf\tex\plain\...` instead of `\localtexmf\text\plain\...`.

Comment: It is easy to look up which file belongs to which package in the packager manager of MiKTeX, in this case `glyphtounicode.tex` belongs to `miktex-pdftex-base-2.9`. So as you still need this I would go for Ulrike's solution.

Comment: @Alexander: Even if the file were in a package you could deinstall: I would never rely on the non-existence of a package or file. With on-the-fly installation it is so easy to reinstall the package some weeks later and then you wonder why your document breaks ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your local file in a folder substructure similar to the other one. That means use `\localtexmf\tex\generic\pdftex`, instead of `\localtexmf\tex\plain\....` See also

[Why isn't kpathsea picking up my local version of a file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79968/why-isnt-kpathsea-picking-up-my-local-version-of-a-file/79983#79983)

And regarding the question in the comment about `ushyphex.tex`: I don't know what the file should do, but if it is for more than one engine or format use `\tex\generic`, if it is specific to a format or an engine use the suitable branch `\tex\<format>`/`\tex\<engine>`.

Comment: As for `ushyphex.tex`, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22867/). The implication is that it belongs into the `\tex\generic` folder, even though the `hyphenex` "package" (not included in MiKTeX) mentioned there (it's in `/tex/generic` on TeXLive) really is for the shell scripts *generating* the `ushyphex.tex` file. Also, I should *probably* put it into a folder `localtexmf\tex\generic\hyphenex` (not a folder `localtexmf\tex\generic\ushyphex`), though this choice isn't entirely clear.