# How does LaTeX resolve path to .sty files?

Tags: kpathsea

I use TeX Live (on a Debian system), and I'm having a new issue with style files.  For many years, I've used a style file I've written called handout.sty; it's in my `~/texmf/tex` directory, and I've always used `\usepackage{handout}` successfully.

I just upgraded my `texlive` distribution to TeX Live 2014; unfortunately, this distribution includes a file also called `handout.sty`, in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/handout/handout.sty`.  Is there a way to set things up so that my `handout.sty` gets precedence?  (I could rename it, but I have literally thousands of TeX files that use it, so I'm not eager to do that.)

I thought this was related to `kpathsea`, but when I run `kpsewhich handout.sty`, it gives the `handout.sty` in my `~/texmf/tex` directory; nonetheless, when I actually run pdflatex on a TeX file, it tries to include the `handout.sty` from the `texlive` distribution.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or how to debug how TeX is looking for the file would be helpful.

Comment: Your personal tree is searched first and once it finds the first handout.sty it quits searching further.

Comment: Put your file in a similar subtree in your local texmf, that means under tex\latex as latex is using a sort of zigzag search path, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79968/why-isnt-kpathsea-picking-up-my-local-version-of-a-file/79983#79983

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike; that fixed it.  (So what is it that kpsewhich is doing then?)

Comment: You need to use -progname=latex to see what latex would find first. E.g.  `kpsewhich -progname=cslatex hyphen.cfg`  finds something different than `kpsewhich -progname=latex hyphen.cfg`.

Comment: There is no need to put it in the local tree @UlrikeFischer. Moving it to the correct sub-directory within the personal tree would do just as well. (Maybe this is what you meant.)

Comment: IIRC it is bad practice to use file names which are already in the texmf tree. You should better call the file Myhandout.sty, that would not get confused and indicate to you and whosoever that is not a file of the texlive.