# MiKTeX and babel: missing file and useless package installation required

Tags: miktex, babel

After not updating my MiKTeX 2.9 for a very long time, I did it a few days ago. I had

`pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16, LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>, babel <3.8m>,`

and now I have

`pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17, LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>, babel <3.9r>.`

Something (bad) happened in between: now, whenever I use the `babel` package (with *any language*), MiKTeX tells me that `bblopts.cfg` is missing and requires the installation of the `arabi` package - which actually contains that file.

Note that I don't even have arabic hyphenation in the format file and, after ignoring that request, the tex file is compiled without errors. Indeed, the rather weird fact is that `bblopts.cfg` is an **optional file**: it only appears in this line of `babel.sty` code:

> `\InputIfFileExists{bblopts.cfg}` ...

Anyway.... To overcome the impasse, since I don't need the `arabi` package, I simply created an empty `bblopts.cfg` file. The **very** weird behaviour of MiKTeX follows:

1. If `bblopts.cfg` is in the tex path, e.g., `C:\localtexmf\tex\generic\babel`,

   - `findtexmf` returns the correct path `C:\localtexmf\tex\generic\babel`,
   - MiKTeX includes `bblopts.cfg`, as the log file shows

     > `* Local config file bblopts.cfg used`
     >   `*`
     >   `(C:\localtexmf\tex\generic\babel\bblopts.cfg).`
   - but it **still** says that `bblopts.cfg` is missing and that I have to install the `arabi` package!
2. If `bblopts.cfg` is in the current folder,

   - `findtexmf` returns the correct path `.\bblopts.cfg`
   - MiKTeX includes `bblopts.cfg`, as the log file shows

     > `* Local config file bblopts.cfg used`
     >   `*`
     >   `(bblopts.cfg).`
   - and **no** warnings or package installation requirements appear!

Does anyone have a clue? Is it just me or is it a MiKTeX bug?? If you want to try, be sure not have the `arabi` package installed and add the `babel` package to your tex file. A toy example could be:

> `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[british]{babel}\begin{document}.\end{document}`

Just in case it matters: my OS is Windows 7 SP1 Enterprise...

Comment: I don't have the `arabi` package installed, and I don't have problems with `babel`. Did you try redoing the formats?

Comment: the bblopts.cfg from arabi is in tex/latex and so first in the search path. Try if it works if you put your file in localtexmf/tex/latex.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't too clear in my question: I never installed the `arabi` package, so I don't have the original `bblopts.cfg` anywhere. What I don't understand is why MiKTeX says that an **optional** file is missing (by definition, `\InputIfFileExists` should do nothing if the file isn't there!), and why it insists in requesting a package that contains that file **even if it finds and includes that file**!

Comment: I have the same problem. Seems like a bug in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bblopts.cfg` from arabi is in `tex\latex`. You put your version in `tex\generic`. Now latex doesn't search first the local texmf tree and then the main tree but follows a sort of zig-zag path (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79983/2388).

This means that when the `\InputIfFileExists` is processed miktex finds first the `bblopts.cfg` from arabi and so tries to download it.

You can avoid this by putting your local file e.g. in `localtexmf\tex\latex\babel`.

Side remark: The `bblopts.cfg` from arabi is imho unnecessary today and should be removed or moved to the doc-folder (where it is in texlive).

Comment: @UlrikeFisher, as far as I can deduce from the MiKTeX manual (no time to look at the source code!), it searches for files in a more linear way than kpath* does (indeed, it says that, inside the 'setting' gui, you "can move [the local files folder] before the installation directory, if you want to prioritize your own files").

Comment: @pav miktex searches through the trees in the same way as kpathsea -- a lot things would break if the search pathes wouldn't be similar to the search pathes in texlive. Beside this: I tested the issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFisher, so the MiKTeX manual is lying!! In any case, please let me undestand better: in my system I have `texmf\tex\generic\babel` and, if I installed the `arabi` package, I would have the `bblopts.cgf` in `texmf\tex\latex\arabi`.  So, why does the fake `bblopts.cgf` in `localtexmf\tex\latex\babel` solve the problem (thanks, by the way!) even if this directory doesn't match with anything else in `texmf`?

Comment: No the manual is not lying. And what matters are the first two subfolders `tex/latex` compared to `tex\generic` . latex will first go through all the `tex\latex`  and then move on to `tex\generic`.

Comment: @UlrikeFisher, maybe I understood: 1. The manual's 'prioritize' means that the search sequence is `localtexmf\tex\latex`, `texmf\tex\latex`, `localtexmf\tex\generic` and so on, thus prioritizing local files wrt files inside _the same subdir_. 2. MiKTeX doesn't find `bblopts.cfg` where the package database says it should be; it tries to download it; I say no; it goes on searching; it finds and inputs the file I actually have; nothing wrong appears in the log file. Right?
Still, I can't understand why the `\InputIfFileExists` of an optional file triggers the whole 'missing-install' thing...

Comment: @Kazibácsi You are linking from an old answer to an old question. It is quite unclear how they relate to your actual problem. It would be better to ask a new question (with a complete example and not a snippet).

Comment: @Kazibácsi I would be *very* carefull with nearly ten years old questions and answers. miktex has changed a lot in the mean time. Beside this I had no problems to activate the patterns in miktex settings and then use them.

Comment: Well I don't know what you did and which answer you used but imho none of them is useful for a portable miktex. Did you check in miktex settings the tab "languages"? Is hungarian mentioned and is it checked?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've provided a MWE and the proposed solution. Can you replicate my error? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373963/hungarian-babel-hyphenation-error

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a MikTeX bug. As a workaround, try

```
\usepackage[noconfigs,british]{babel}
```

The option `noconfigs` does what its name suggests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @JavierBezos, but I was looking for an explanation rather than a workaround. Besides, that way I should change every file I use (due to a bug that could disappear in a month) and I wouldn't be able to use a configuration file that, someday, could be useful...