# My section titles got weird spaces

Tags: sectioning

The title has become like this for almost every \subsubsection and \section.

[image]

```
\section{Statics of a particle}

\subsection{equilibrium and solving equation}
```

Here's what i use for package and renew command. (if you need more information and at which area please tell me)

This is the error message:

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 422--422

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{grffile} 
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Mechanics 1 Content}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}
```

Also I have another question about latex telling me to download a package ;

The required file:
tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg

which is uninstallable. Is this a part of the problem? I'm not sure why its trying to install that package every time.

Here is my full code.... I just think it's easier for you to see the whole picture;

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57a8479fee5936ac58848ea6

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, simply copy and paste the code into the website. Then you can highlight it all and hit ctrl + k (or use the code sample button, which looks like {}) to apply the correct markdown

Comment: Ok gotcha Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: No problem that's much better. You might also find it helpful to check out [our page about how to build a minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: This is not an answer to your first question, but to your second one. [I've seen that error before](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313539/miktex-and-babel-missing-file-and-useless-package-installation-required), you can check for solutions there (multiple listed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the only complaint i had about the formatting of the (sub)section headings
was the dreadful spacing, i'd simply add `\raggedright` to the basic definitions:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedright}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries\raggedright}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}}
\makeatother
```

(these are lifted directly from `book.cls`, with `\newcommand` changed to
`\renewcommand`, and `\raggedright` added at the end of the content
specification.)

Comment: just to be sure after adding these to my commands I just use section, subsection and subsubsection normally with the commands \section, \subsection and \subsubsection respecively right? I tried that,but it again issued error message.. undefined controlled sequence \section, you cant use\spacefactor in maths mode and missing $ inserted

Comment: @MewLeenutaphong -- yes. you don't need to change your input.  these definitions are direct replacements.

Comment: I tried to add \section{name} and \subsection{name}, but it says "spacefactor error" and missing $$ sign.. Thanks again

Comment: @MewLeenutaphong: Use a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair around the code provided by Barbara. The `\@startsection` etc. commands are `at-letter` commands and can't be used directly in a document.

Comment: Thanks man it worked, but I have one more issue.... The chapter number said 0.5.1 and i wanted it to be something like 5.1 . i want to get rid of the "0" . I dont want to use \chapter because it creates an unessary page.. what should I do .. THANks a lot man!

Comment: you're using `\documentclass{book}` but you don't use `\chapter`.  that's why you're getting the zero.  if you just want to get rid of blank pages between chapters, use the documentclass option `[openany]` and *do* use `\chapter`.  (each chapter will start on a new page, but there won't be any blanks between.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: There was nothing to correct actually. The problem is the LaTeX source actually. While `\@...` commands are nice to hide some implementation as soon as some user-request about changing parameters/settings increases the level of difficulty for unexperienced users...and you know that I don't like editing answers.

Comment: OK THanks a lot!!!! You saved me... I have no more problem left :)

Answer (score 0):

I compiled this code and it looks fine:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{grffile} 
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Mechanics 1 Content}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}



\begin{document}

    \section{Statics of a particle}

    \subsection{equilibrium and solving equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll send you the whole code tonight and let you compile it.

Comment: This is the error message that pops up as I press compile .... Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 422--422

Comment: I have 6 sections in my work, the first two had no error message, but the last four had this \hbox (badness 10000) at each sections and subsection. It makes no sense why that should happen to the last ones, but not the first...

Comment: Please kindly crop your embedded image.

Comment: I'm not sure which embedded image you meant ... the one existing in the forum of my post? .. Thankyou

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57a8479fee5936ac58848ea6   can you try compile these codes? thanks