# Problem with latest version of babel

Tags: babel, bugs

I have a problem with that latest version of babel (3.10). If I compile this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ukenglish]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Then I get the message

```
LaTeX Error: Command \setlocale already defined.
```

Why is that?

Here is my log file (this time, I used spanish instead of ukenglish):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.5.8)  29 MAY 2017 11:13
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9t> and hyphenation patterns for 74 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2017/05/19 3.10 The Babel package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\switch.def"
File: switch.def 2017/05/19 3.10 Babel switching mechanism


! LaTeX Error: Command \setlocale already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \endgroup 
l.301     {Find an armchair, sit down and wait}}

? 
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-spanish\spanish.ldf"
Language: spanish.ldf 2016/03/03 v5.0p Spanish support from the babel system

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2017/05/19 3.10 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\es@quottoks=\toks14
\es@quotdepth=\count88
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 561.
Package babel Info: Making . an active character on input line 662.
Package babel Info: Making < an active character on input line 707.
Package babel Info: Making > an active character on input line 707.
)) (test.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 6.
)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 6.

[1

{C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (test.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 6.
)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2017/05/19 3.10 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
 spanish.ldf
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1053 strings out of 493330
 13040 string characters out of 3139261
 74021 words of memory out of 3000000
 4656 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,4n,30p,169b,359s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12297 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the `File list` from the `.log` into the question?  You might also point to the path of `ukenglish.ldf` (doesn't seem to have a file version).

Comment: Sure. Here is the file list: *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2017/05/19 3.10 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
ukenglish.ldf

Comment: Note that this problem arises for any language that I use.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313539/miktex-and-babel-missing-file-and-useless-package-installation-required/313676 I suspect: with TeX Live I don't get `bblopts.cfg` listed and have no issues with the demo (other file versions the same).

Comment: I tried copying `bblopts.cfg` in the working directory, but I don't get  the error (on TeX Live). Same file list.

Comment: It is a related problem, but not the same one. I am using MiKTeX indeed, but at the question for which you posted a link there is no mention to the error message that I mentioned.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What do you get for your LaTeX format version? I have `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.` (start of the `.log`).

Comment: Same thing (almost) here: LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 74 language(s) loaded.

Comment: You could add `\errorcontextlines=1000` as the first line of your document then post the log you get from the above test file, in a code block so lone endings are preserved.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error and I don't see why bblopts.cfg should matter. Can you show your log file?

Comment: Note that I do not get therror if I compile using LaTeX; only when I use PDFLaTeX. I shall edit my original post in otder to add the log file.

Comment: Your babel version in the format (Babel <3.9t>) differ from the one loaded as package. You probably should recreate the formats (probably you have a user version of the format and should use the user version of miktex settings).

Comment: That suggestion solved the problem. Thanks a lot, Ulrike.

Comment: It's a bug, which will be fixed in the next release. But the workaround provided by Ulrike should work - just recreate the formats.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have the same problem
What are the steps of the solution

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have the same problem
What are the steps of the solution

Comment: @Emadkareem Like I said in the comments, I recreated the formats.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error with `babel` version 3.12.

However, you should change `ukenglish` into `UKenglish`. The `ukenglish` option has never existed, but due to the filesystem in Windows being case insensitive, the correct file `UKenglish.ldf` is loaded anyway under that OS.