# Hungarian Babel hyphenation error

Tags: babel, hyphenation, hungarian

I have just downloaded MikTeX Portable, installed the latest Babel package on-the-fly (with this strange *[arabi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313539/miktex-and-babel-missing-file-and-useless-package-installation-required)* package), and still got a hyphenation error with Hungarian Babel:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\begin{document}
Kipróbáljuk, hogy működik-e az elválasztás hosszú szavaknál: megszentségteleníthetetlenségeskedéseitekért.
\end{document}
```

> Package magyar.ldf Warning: All Hungarian hyphenation= patterns
>   missing. To make LaTeX hyphenate Hungarian words, please modify
>   language.dat and rerun initex or texconfig.

I'm using Windows 10 and TeXnicCenter 2.02 if that matters. Do you have any ideas how may I solve it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gained inspiration from this old [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758992/miktex-2-8-doesnt-add-hyphenation-support-for-pdflatex). The only thing I had to do was to go to the `\texmfs\install\miktex\bin` folder, run `mo.exe` and on the *General* tab press *Update formats.* After that everything works perfectly, no warning messages, correct hyphenation.

**Edit:**

Please note that in [more recent versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460444/135685), the `mo.exe` was replaced with the console.

Comment: Doing something with admin rights on a portable installation can't be right or necessary. It is quite possible that you need to recreate the formats to activate the patterns, but then better do it through the miktex terminal you can see in the tray icon. Call there mo.exe to open miktex settings.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fair point, and admin mode is not needed at all eventually (so I've edited it out). To answer your other question, Hungarian was checked among the languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a lot of things, for example the `magyar.ldf` from this website: https://math.bme.hu/latex/

Comment: The file is there, it's just not recognised by the system somehow :-(

Comment: It should be on LaTeX's path, the easiest to do that is by simply placing it into the same folder as your tex file.