# XeLaTeX not giving priority to .cbx files in local texmf tree

Tags: biblatex, xetex, texinputs

I just installed MacTeX on a new machine. I'm running into a difficulty I hadn't had before.

I have a `.cbx` file inside `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/` that has the same name as another `.cbx` file inside `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex`.

If I run LaTeX on a file calling the corresponding citation style (`\usepackage[citestyle=name-of-cbx-file]{biblatex}`) the `.cbx` file inside the `texmf` tree inside `~/Library` is given priority. If I run `xelatex` on the same file, however, the one that is inside `texmf-dist` is given priority.

This is the output of `kpsewhich -expand-var='$TEXINPUTS'`:

```
.:{{}/Users/apc/Library/texlive/2017/texmf-config,/Users/apc/Library/texlive/2017/texmf-var,/Users/apc/Library/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist}/tex/{kpsewhich,generic,}//
```

Shouldn't `xelatex` and `latex` be searching for `biblatex` style files in the same way? If so, why is `xelatex` not finding the files?

Comment: You have one of the cbx in `latex` the other in `xelatex`. This changes the search pathes. Put both below `latex`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79983/2388

Comment: Got it. That link was quite helpful. I was under the impression that moving files around inside texmf-dist is not a long-term solution, since updates to TeXLive will likely undo that. Is that not true?

Comment: I've created a symlink to the file inside the local `xelatex` folder. Would that be a better solution, long-term?

Comment: Normally you shouldn't change the locations in texmf-dist. But imho the location of a cbx in `tex/xelatex` is wrong. Who put it there?

Comment: Seems to be part of this package, which was included with MacTeX: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/langsci

Comment: I see. Well as I wrote: imho the standard location is badly choosen. If you want to add a local version of this cbx you should put it in tex/xelatex in your local texmf.

Comment: Thanks. I don't to use that file (it doesn't actually work with the latest version of `biblatex` anyway) so I guess I can remove the package from texmf-dist using the texlive utility or something. Tricking xetex into looking for the local file using symlinks seems to be working for now. Thanks for your help!